# TextArea validate input is valid/safe HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea that users can input HTML.  When they hit preview I place the textarea in a div and let them preview it.

I'm looking for an easy way to:

1. Disable all malicious code.
2. Validate the text area is not going to cause issues when showing in the div.  For example if there is an input like:

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('hi there'); '
 </script>
```

The ' is not a typo... if I let that happen I get into a bad state.  But I think if i disable all scripts I should be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [PageDown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) to handle escaping on the client side. You'll want to glance at the documentation, in particular the Sanitizer section that will remove malicious HTML/Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend try to avoid preview in Javascript and post your datas to server side and validate and then show Preview.

Comment: I do all three, i validate on client side, and the validate again on server side, and again on pull from db...

Comment: @Nix if your server side PHP, you can use filter_var() function and select option SANITIZE STRING to avoid scripts run on input